# GUID Behind the Scenes

Tags: guid

I am wondering, what goes into the creation of a GUID. I don't mean what is used to create a GUID in a specific language (NewID() in SQL Server, Guid.NewGuid() in C#), I mean when you call those methods/functions, what do they do to make the GUID?

Comment: Are you looking for something more than [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier)?

Answer (score 3):

Also, [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) (which is referenced in the Wikipedia article) describes how GUIDs should be built.

Answer (score 2):

The details of GUIDs, including the algorithm used to generate them is described on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier).

Answer (score 1):

In short, it's not complicated at all. **GUID** (or UUID) Version 4 (current) **is a** partially **random number**, plain and simple (122 out of 128 bits are random, the rest are used for storing version and revision). The trick is that **the possible values of this number are so many that the probability of a hit is** for most practical purposes, **zero**.

Comment: I would say that it is a partially random number. Some parts of it are not random at all.

Comment: Some of the bits are created from the machine info and don't change as long as your on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Hash function. Its complicated.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID#Algorithm Knows more than I do.

Answer (score 0):

A word of caution that a very great deal of what you read on the Internet about GUID creation may well be wrong, or at least out of date for your specific platform.

I once single-stepped through a heap of Windows code to settle an argument about GUID creation on WinXP.  Unfortunately, it turned out that I was wrong (i.e. I lost the argument), but so was Larry Osterman, so I felt slightly better about it.

Answer (score 0):

There are five official ways of generating GUID's (and certainly many more unofficial ones).

- Version 1 is a time based GUID usually using MAC addresses of the primary network card of the using used to compute the GUID. This is normally not used due to privacy issues, but I do believe that Microsoft SQL Servers from 2005 and onwards use a modified version of this (claiming to be version 14), to create sequential GUID's useful for id's in a database to avoid fractioning of data blocks (NewSequentialId()).
- Version 2 is DCE Security version. I have never found this kind of GUID, but I have not worked a lot with POSIX either and there seems to be a connection between version 2 GUID's and POSIX.
- Version 3 is a "name based" version, meaning you can take a text and create a GUID representation of that, given a namespace. Version 3 uses a MD5 hashing algorithm. See also version 5.
- Version 4 is basically a random number type GUID. The random number is of sequrity level, not just your average random number generator though. This is the version usually used in the world today. The C# Guid.NewGuid() uses this version, according to Microsoft documentation. Also the normal function for generating an uniqueidentifier in MS SQL Server (NewId()) generates a version 4 GUID.
- Version 5 is just like version 3, but uses a SHA-3 hashing algorithm instead. The [extended guid C# project](http://guidex.codeplex.com/) uses the version 5 algorithm.

For one implementation of GUID making I'd recomend looking at the extended guid project. As many has pointed out the [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) gives a detailed description on how all five algorithms work. However, there are no guarantees all implementations are correct.