# GUIDs in a C++ Linux GCC app

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, guid

I've got a bunch of servers running this Linux app.  I'd like for them to be able to generate a GUID with a low probability of collision.  I'm sure I could just pull 128 bytes out of /dev/urandom and that would probably be fine, but is there a simple & easy way to generate a GUID that is more equivalent to the Win32 one?  Specifically, one that takes into account space (well, MAC address), time, and randomness?  I don't want to call off the box for it, I just want something like [CreateGuid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa713311.aspx)

Comment: Look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87127/guid-behind-the-scenes P.S. This is **not** a duplicate question - the best answer would point to a publicly available source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [Internet Draft](http://www.webdav.org/specs/draft-leach-uuids-guids-01.txt) describes one type of UUID in great details and I have used a similar approach with great success when I needed a UUID implementation and could not link to an existing library for architectural reasons.

This [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier) provides a good overview.

Comment: From looking at that second link, I found libuuid (http://linux.die.net/man/3/libuuid), which seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 8):

There is [libuuid](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libuuid).

Comment: It would be wonderful if there were a non-LGPL (and non-GPL) library.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: Why do you care about LGPL libraries when targeting Linux C++? The C++ standard library is LGPL.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use something then an Internet standard would be a good idea:
Check out RFC (Request For Comment).

The one I know that is specific to GUID is:
[RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt)

Answer (score -2):

There is a Boost version available.

http://www.boostpro.com/vault/index.php?action=downloadfile&filename=uuid_v11.zip&directory=&PHPSESSID=69e18b945f686398b963710fd52f143a

Comment: It would be useful if down-voters would leave a comment.  Sigh.