# How do I obtain/use LibUUID?

Tags: linux, gcc, uuid, guid

I'm trying to replace a call to `::CoCreateGUID` so I can generate GUIDs in a C++ program on Linux.

I understand that [libuuid](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libuuid) supports this, and I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153676/guids-in-a-c-linux-gcc-app).

I'm a bit new to Ubuntu/GCC/Linux, so I've started off like this:

```
#include <uuid/uuid.h>
```

And now I'm stuck! :)  G++ can't find `uuid.h`, and I'm not sure how to get/find it.

Comment: To expand the topic, on Gentoo:* Searching for /usr/include/uuid/uuid.h ... 
sys-apps/util-linux-2.18-r1 (/usr/include/uuid/uuid.h)

Comment: Also worth noting is, that on current Linux kernels you can get a uuid by reading /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid

Answer (score 87, accepted):

In Ubuntu, you can do `apt-cache search libuuid` to see the available packages relating to the text `libuuid`.  Here's my output from Ubuntu 9.04:

```
$ apt-cache search libuuid
libuuid-perl - Perl extension for using UUID interfaces as defined in e2fsprogs
libuuid1 - universally unique id library
libuuid1-dbg - Debugging information for libuuid1
uuid-dev - universally unique id library - headers and static libraries
uuid-runtime - universally unique id library
libuuidm-ocaml-dev - Universally unique identifiers for OCaml
```

So I think the one you want is uuid-dev, and possibly uuid-runtime.  Perform the command `sudo apt-get install uuid-dev`, and it should install the headers and libraries you need to move on past the problem you're having.

Comment: thx, that looks like what I was missing, I ran this: "apt-get install uuid-dev" and that solved my problem.

Comment: NB that on CentOS there are both `libuuid-dev` and `uuid-dev`, choose wisely...

Comment: its worth mentioning that this is quite hacky and requires an ifdef to make it on other OS. Macports offers `port install libuuid `, homebrew however does not. uuid is part of macOS however.

Answer (score 18):

It's also worth mentioning that this is part of util-linux available here:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/

Comment: This would be for those how wish to compile the package from the source.  If you are using Ubuntu (or Debian), the `apt-get` of the **dev** packages is the appropriate solution.

Comment: Here is alpine image, the package name: `util-linux-dev` will add `libuuid-dev`